# Insert html into a contenteditable but add new text after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a contenteditable div, and a button that adds a simple span.

```
<button id="insert-span">Insert</button>
<div id="edit-box" contenteditable="true"></div>
<script>
    $('#insert-span').on('click', function() {
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', null, '<span class="inserted">Hi</span>');
    });
</script>
```

When I click the button, the span is correctly added to the div, but when I go to enter more text it is inside the inserted span, so I end up with this

```
<div id="edit-box" contenteditable="true">
    <span class="inserted">Hi and then all the other text I enter</span>
</div>
```

Is there any way start the entering of text outside the span tag, so that I end up with something like this

```
<div id="edit-box" contenteditable="true">
    <span class="inserted">Hi</span> and then all the other text I enter
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you would do that but this should do it:

```
var text = document.createTextNode('your text after the span');
edit_box.appendChild(text);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for me as I need to add the span multiple times in the contenteditable div.  The scenario is this, the user is typing along, clicks the Insert button, keeps typing, clicks the button again, and repeat.

Comment: You just keep appending span or text. I don't see what your problem is

Comment: So if the user just keeps typing after clicking the Insert button I capture their input and append it as a textNode after the current content?

Comment: Yes, it should work. You can append as many node (whatever the kind of node) as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using the jquery prepend method here, since you're already using jQuery?

```
$('#insert-span').on('click', function() {     
    $('#edit-box').prepend('<span class="inserted">Hi</span> and then all the other text I enter');
});
```

Comment: I need to be able to add the span at any point in the text of the div.

Comment: $('#insert-span').on('click', function() {     
      $('<i>and then all the other text I enter</i>').insertAfter('span');
    });